# Can GTK libraries used with Plutus?

Tags: plutus, haskell, plutus-pab

Interested in GUI interfaces, is their restriction's in using GTK Haskell libraries with Plutus.
Am only starting on Journey so wanted general feedback that might help guide me down right path.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I can't think of a reason why they won't work together.

Comment: Thank you Sjoerd, I will move forward to try with one of my small project Ideas.